# devise customization in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am implementing devise for user registration but some customizations and it is below.

- When user registers with username,email and password, an email will go to user
- In email user will get a secret code which is required to complete sign up process.
- When user clicks "Go to App" button, It will redirect user to App and here user has to use  that secret code to complete sign up process.
- Once user completes sign up process, there would be one to one relationship between user and that secret code.

I searched a lot on internet but could not find answer.

Problem: I do not know how to create secret code in rails and then send it to user thourgh email and then match it with code that user got.

Note: Secret code and password are two different things in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Devise has an internal module called `Confirmable` that does exactly this.

In order to use it, all you need to do is:

- Make sure your devise model is `:confirmable` and `:registerable`

  ```
  class User
    # ...
    devise :confirmable, :registerable ...
    # ...
  end
  ```
- Run a migration that creates confirmation_token fields

  ```
  class AddConfirmableToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
      change_table(:users) do |t|
        t.confirmable
      end
      add_index :users, :confirmation_token, :unique => true
    end

    def self.down
       remove_column :users, :confirmable
    end
  end
  ```

If you already have users, and don't want them to follow this confirmation process, than you need to make them confirmed. You can do that doing

```
User.update_all ["confirmed_at = ?", Time.now]
```

on the console.

More references: [Confirable Module](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable), [Adding confirmable to Users in Devise](http://tommcfarlin.com/adding-confirmable-to-users-in-devise/)